# How do the items and sizes rules apply to consumables

Tags: pathfinder-2e, equipment, creature-size

A tiny character, such as a Sprite, can have their weapon and armor adjusted to their size.

When the adventuring party now loots Healing Potions, I assume they are regular sized potions. They will be treated as 1 bulk for the tiny creature.

Is it possible to adapt/craft (e.g.) Healing Potions to be of tiny size, reducing the Bulk to negligible for medium creatures and to light for tiny creatures?

Comment: This almost feels like a necessity for tiny alchemists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can typically find/craft Tiny items

The rules for [Gear](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=236) include the [Items and Sizes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=256) rules and cover "all sorts of items both while exploring and in downtime, ranging from rations to climbing gear to fancy clothing, depending on the situation."

> Creatures of sizes other than Small or Medium need items appropriate to their size. These items have different Bulk and possibly a different Price. Table 6–20 provides the Price and Bulk conversion for such items.

This is not specifically about weapons and armor, all items can be found in various sizes.

Comment: Not to mention the currency itself.

Comment: I wonder, does the game give any indication/reason for a medium alchemist not to craft tiny items only, just to reduce the weight? (Not that it's that important normally)

Comment: I doubt it, but as a GM (and the GM is given ample latitude in the rules), I would say that you need to make appropriately sized items if you want to gain their full effects. I know that causes some issues with fighting larger creatures using bombs and poisons, but I wouldn't put up with that kind of min-maxxing without a good story reason. Most alchemists are going to be *used* to making stuff their size.